# Is there a way to reboot an iOS app?

Tags: ios

I am pretty new to iOS and was wondering if there was a way to restart an app. Essentially when you reach the end of the app it gives you the option of restarting the whole app. The instances are reset along with everything else. I could go back to the first screen and reset instances manually, but I was wondering if there was a way I could have the app restart or reboot itself.

Comment: No, you can't restart or reboot an app without private APIs and/or a jailbreak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you familiar with the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller) design pattern? You should have your application data stored in a model object. When the user "gets to the end", you can reset the model and update your views to start over.

Comment: How do I reset to another view controller at the end?

Comment: If you've put all your model data into your model object, you shouldn't need to reset to another view controller at the end. Your view controller should have no state that doesn't rely on the model. That way when the model is reset, the view and view controller just keep showing what's in the model now and everything should be the new state.